# What is the best to implement video calling to React Native app?

Tags: react-native, videocall

I’m developing a React-Native app and I want implement video calling option to it. Can somebody suggest me some better examples?

Comment: better than what? What do you have now (have you tried anything?)

Comment: Yes. Webrtc, and few others. But I’m still confused and can’t get anything to be working

Comment: https://medium.com/agora-io/add-video-calling-in-cross-platform-mobile-apps-using-the-agora-io-react-native-sdk-2fd515bb8add check this once

Comment: Yes I tried that. It was ok. But didn’t get the users in video list. I only used simulator and one android physical device. It creates a random user ID and once I enter to the channel, only my own device camera video was there. Is there something more to do? Like configuring a server or something?

Comment: Ok I finally made it working. Thanks to @GauravRoy. Now I have another question. I can add users to the group video call. It's fine. But, is it possible to start multiple video calls between 2 people? I mean A and B people, X and Y, ...

Comment: for multiple video calls i think you would require a backend so that there is a consistency.

Comment: So I can do multiple user video chats in a single channel?